# Hibernate and deleting from lists

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got two classes, ProductConfiguration and SubProduct.

I want to replace the subproducts on the configuration, which I do in this way:

```
productConfiguration.getSubProducts().clear();
productConfiguration.getSubProducts().addAll(newSubProducts);
```

In doing this, Hibernate attempts to set the ID of the parent (the product configuration) to null, and then update the row in the database. This fails, as the parent ID is a foreign key, and therefore not nullable.

The mapping from ProductConfiguration to SubProduct:

```
<bag name="subProducts"
     table="sub_product"
     cascade="all-delete-orphan"
     access="field"
     lazy="false">
    <key column="parent_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="com.conscius.cpt.core.product.SubProduct"/>
</bag>

<many-to-one name="parentProduct"
             class="com.conscius.cpt.core.product.ProductConfiguration"
             column="parent_id"
             access="field"
             not-null="true"
             cascade="none"/>
```

Comment: Do you intend for a sub product to exist in the database at all when its parent gets deleted? If not, have a look at this: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-bidir

Comment: I see where I went wrong. I was missing the inverse statement on the ProductConfiguration side. I will add the answer ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is simple. I forgot to add an inverse statement to the product configuration side.

```
<bag name="subProducts"
     table="sub_product"
     cascade="all-delete-orphan"
     access="field"
     lazy="false">
    <key column="parent_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="com.conscius.cpt.core.product.SubProduct"/>
</bag>
```

Answer (score 1):

if the foreign key is not nullable you probably want to delete SubProducts which have no parent:

```
<bag name="subProducts" cascade="all-delete-orphan" ...
```

Update: to prevent the updates of the foreign key you can do

```
<bag name="subProducts" inverse="true" ...

// and
for (SubProduct sub : productConfiguration.getSubProducts())
{
    sub.setParentProduct(null);
}
productConfiguration.getSubProducts().clear();
productConfiguration.getSubProducts().addAll(newSubProducts);
```

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I actually had that before, but figured that might have been the issue. It was not, and I have reinserted the delete-orphan part.